# How to solve inequality with absolute values?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, solution-verification

I was given a task which I solved but now I am not sure if my way is correct, so I would be thankful if someone would verify my solution and maybe give me some tips for improvement.

I have to find an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $a_N-\frac{2}{3}<0,01$ holds **for the first time**. Here $a_n$ is defined like the following: $a_n:=\frac{2n+6}{3n+8}\in\mathbb{R}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I did this with equivalent transformations of the inequality and came to the solution that the inequality holds the first time for $N=20$.

Now I have to investigate if the inequality $\lvert a_n-\frac{2}{3}\rvert<0,01$ holds for every $n\geq N$.

This part is giving more points than the first part, which confuses me a bit. Because my idea now was that I only have to show that $a_n-\frac{2}{3}\geq0$ holds. Then I can remove the absolute and would just use the same equivalent transformations than before and I would come to the solution that $\lvert a_n-\frac{2}{3}\rvert<0,01$ indeed holds for every $n\geq N$.

To show that $a_n-\frac{2}{3}\geq0$ I just did the following:

$$a_n-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2n+6}{3n+8}-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{3(3n+8)}$$
Because $n\in\mathbb{N}$ this is obviously greater than $0$.

Now I can remove the absolute and just do the same as before. Is this everything I have to do or am I missing something?

### Whole Solution

Since @CalvinLin pointed out that it's best if I write down my whole solution here it is:

First I have to find an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $a_N-\frac{2}{3}<0,01$ holds the first time. I did this with transformations of the inequality:

$$\begin{align*}
    & &a_N-\frac{2}{3}&<0,01 & &|\, 0,01=\frac{1}{100}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow &\frac{2N+6}{3N+8}-\frac{2}{3}&<\frac{1}{100} & &|\, -\frac{1}{100} \\
    &\Leftrightarrow &\frac{2N+6}{3N+8}-\frac{203}{300}&<0 \\
    &\Leftrightarrow &\frac{300(2N+6)}{300(3N+8)}-\frac{203(3N+8)}{300(3N+8)}&<0 & &|\,300(3N+8)\neq0, \cdot300(3N+8) \\
    &\Leftrightarrow &300(2N+6)-203(3N+8)&<0 \\
    &\Leftrightarrow &(600N+1800)-(609N+1624)&<0 \\
    &\Leftrightarrow &600N+1800-609N-1624&<0 \\
    &\Leftrightarrow &-9N+176&<0 & &|\, -176\\
    &\Leftrightarrow &-9N&<-176 & &|\, :(-9)\\
    &\Leftrightarrow &N&>\frac{176}{9}
\end{align*}$$
We found that the inequation holds the first time for $N=\lceil\frac{176}{9}\rceil=20$.

Now I have to investigate if the inequality $\lvert a_n-\frac{2}{3}\rvert<0,01$ holds for every $n\geq N$.

The following holds: $a_n-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2n+6}{3n+8}-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{3(3n+8)}$. Because $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\frac{2}{3(3n+8)}>0\Leftrightarrow a_n-\frac{2}{3}>0$.

Hence $a_n-\frac{2}{3}>0\Rightarrow\lvert a_n-\frac{2}{3}\rvert=a_n-\frac{2}{3}$

From this follows: $\lvert a_n-\frac{2}{3}\rvert<0,01\Leftrightarrow a_n-\frac{2}{3}<0,01$. We are now solving the inequation $a_n-\frac{2}{3}<0,01$ like above and find that $\lvert a_n-\frac{2}{3}\rvert<0,01$ holds for every $n\geq\lceil\frac{176}{9}\rceil$. Because $N=\lceil\frac{176}{9}\rceil$ the inequality  $\lvert a_n-\frac{2}{3}\rvert<0,01$ indeed holds for every $n\geq N$.

Comment: At the start, are you wanting to find an $N$ such that $ a_N  - 2/3 < 0, 01$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I want to find an $N$ such that $a_N-\frac{2}{3}<0,01$ holds for the **first time**. I already did that and found $N=20$.

Comment: To clarify, what I meant was that you're likely missing the absolute sign in the first inequality. IE You want $ | a_N - 2/3 | < 0, 01$.

Comment: @CalvinLin The task is exactly written like the following: "For which $N\in\mathbb{N}$ is $a_N-\frac{2}{3}<0,01$ valid for the first time?" No absolute signs. This is the first part which I already solved, then the second part is: "Is the inequality $\lvert a_n-\frac{2}{3}\rvert<0,01$ valid for every $n\geq N$?" I am sorry if I didn't point that out exact enough.

Comment: Ah, I was confused by your writeup. I didn't realize that you had 2 tasks, the first of which is when does $a_N - 2/3 < 0, 01$ which you have resolved, and the second of which is if $|a_N - 2/3 | < 0,01$ holds for every $n \neq N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to find $n$ such that
$$\left|a_n - \frac{2}{3}\right| < \frac{1}{100}$$
Since $a_n = \frac{2n + 6}{3n + 8}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{2n + 6}{3n + 8} - \frac{2}{3}\right| & < \frac{1}{100}\\
\left|\frac{6n + 18}{3(3n + 8)} - \frac{6n + 16}{3(3n + 8)}\right| & < \frac{1}{100}\\
\left|\frac{2}{3(3n + 8)}\right| & < \frac{1}{100}
\end{align*}
If $0 < a < b$, then $\frac{1}{a} > \frac{1}{b}$, which can be seen by multiplying both sides of the inequality $a < b$ by $\frac{1}{ab} > 0$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{3(3n + 8)}{2}\right| & > 100\\
|3(3n + 8)| & > 200\\
|9n + 24| & > 200
\end{align*}
Since $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $9n + 24 > 0 \implies |9n + 24| = 9n + 24$.
\begin{align*}
9n + 24 & > 200\\
9n & > 176\\
n & > \frac{176}{9}
\end{align*}
Hence, the distance of $a_n$ from $2/3$ is less than $1/100$ whenever $n > 176/9$.  The smallest such $n$ is
$$N = \left\lceil \frac{176}{9} \right\rceil = 20$$
as you found.

Comment: Why is the step where I am multiplying the inequality $a<b$ with $\frac{1}{ab}$ necessary? Can't we just say that $a_n=\frac{2}{3(3n+8)}>0$ holds because $n\in\mathbb{N}$? And because this holds $\lvert a_n-\frac{2}{3}\rvert<0,01\Leftrightarrow a_n-\frac{2}{3}<0,01$. And now we would just continue with the usual transformations?

Comment: What we both proved is that $\left|a_n - \frac{2}{3}\right| = \left|\frac{2}{3(3n + 8)}\right|$.  What we must determine is the values of $n$ for which $\left|\frac{2}{3(3n + 8)}\right| < \frac{1}{100}$, which is why I solved the inequality for $n$.  What you did is show that $2/3$ is a lower bound for the sequence.

Comment: I  now added a whole writeup of my solution. Where I am just using the fact that $a_n-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{3(3n+8)}>0$ holds. Can you maybe look over it?

Comment: What you wrote is correct.  You can avoid some of those steps by working with the absolute value inequality from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, in the writeup of only the second part, you have not shown that for any $ n > N$, $a_n - 2/3 < 0, 01$. I know you said "Then I can remove the absolute and would just use the same equivalent transformations than before", but esp for a solution-verification, it's best to have the entire thing written up.

The rest is fine.